# How to make single page to open in landscape mode only..Not whole application ?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm facing a Problem with my list . There is button naming List ..on click of it I'm showing list overlay, but due to more columns I have to make user to see it in landscape mode only..How would I achieve it ? I have made my whole Project orientation as Portrait . And I want to show this page in Landscape only...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of is to create a landscape and portrait profile for that view and toggle them based on a listener for orientationchange.

I have a feeling though that will like the way that works even less.  You may be better off rethinking that layout all together.

Good luck, Brad